# PHP - Form made from a loop forgets its values

Tags: php

There's a form in PHP script, which is made from while loop. Like:

```
$z = 1;
While ($x < $y)
{
    $reminder = $_POST["entry$z"];
    echo "<input type='text' name='entry".$z."' value='".$reminder."' size='50' />"
    $z++;
}
```

My script remembers other values, when you change the pages, but not that from the loop.
Does someone know why? Have a solution? Thanks!

Comment: please show us the full html code / php code.

Comment: What's the content of your $_POST (print_r($_POST))? Why do you use the $reminder variable? At the end of the echo command a ; is missing...

Comment: The result print_r($_POST) is right, all values get transfered to the next site. The problem is that the values disappear, when I move one page back.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have defined values for the $x and the $y in the loop?

Also close the echo with a ;

Answer (score 0):

The text box will have the value you set with the value attribute, in your case $reminder. You could set the default value to something from the $_REQUEST array instead which will contain the form values from last time the form was submitted.

Something like $_REQUEST['entry'.$z] instead of $reminder would do it.

EDIT: didn't see the line above the textbox creation where you define that variable. Just change it to $_POST['entry'.$z]

Comment: I've tried your way with $_REQUEST. It gives ratherly the same result :/

Comment: Yeah sorry, I actually forgot that PHP renders variables in double quotes! I shouldn't answer questions about languages I haven't used in years.